# Variable out of range or failed to be recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I need some advice for my code. I really appreciate if some members can edit my code. Thanks

My code below is looking for the name on column B and copy the result on another sheet if 2 conditions met: 
- The row.value on column G = "ongoing"
- The row.value on column C = "HP"

When I run this code, got an error-message box "Range of Object"_Worksheet failed.

I am trying to change the set "mytable to ShSReturn.ListObject ("Survey Return")" with mytable as Range, another message error "Subscription out of range"

```
Sub LOf()

    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim myrange As Long, lastrow As Long, finalrow As Long, resultrow As Long
    Dim mytable As Range

    lastrow = ShSReturn.Range("G" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    finalrow = ShSReturn.Range("C" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    resultrow = ShSReturn.Range("B" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects("Survey Return")

    cell = 7

    For Each cell In mytable
        If mytable.Cells(cell, lastrow).Value = "Ongoing" _
        And mytable.Cells(cell, finalrow).Value = "HP" Then

        mytable.Cells(cell, resultrow).Copy
        ShPPT.Cells(cell, 17).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        resultrow = resultrow + 1

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Line `Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects("Survey Return")` is not right, because you defined `mytable` as a range object, so you must set it to a range object. `ShSReturn.ListObjects("Survey Return")` returns a `ListObject`. Is not the same. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject

Comment: Also, why are you setting `cell = 7`? That does nothing useful.

Comment: `cell` is a `Range` object.  In `.Cells(cell, lastrow)` etc, `cell` will return its default property which is `value`.  You probably want `.Cells(cell.column, lastrow)`.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns on ShSReturn, I have a table called "Survey Return" and I want the my macro to run on this table to find 2 condition before copy the result on another sheet. What should I do for declaration my variable "mytable"?

Comment: @ChrisMelville I want to set my code to run starting from row "7", doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @aucuparia Thanks for your answer. I will try it. Do you have any idea to change "mytable" variable declaration because I was stuck on it and I can go further with my code without reassigning new declaration

Comment: Define MyTable as `ListObject`. Then, in the link I provided before, you can check for properties and methos of a `ListObject` object. Check some of them to see what you need, but probably you want this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks for your feedback. I defined mytable as listobjects and Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects.Item("Survey Return").DataBodyRange, why I got a message error "subscript out of range", I checked it my code name and I didn't misspell it, why macro can't find my sheet "ShSReturn"?

Comment: If you have defined `mytable` as ListObject, then try `Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects("Survey Return")`. But now that I readi it properly, `Survey Return` **is not** a valid name for tables. Names for tables **can't** contain spaces or blanks. Are you sure `Survey Return` is a table object?

Comment: Eventhough, I wrote like this, Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects("SurveyReturn").Item.DataBodyRange. I got another error message "Object doesn't support the property or method"

Comment: I guess then your table name is `SurveyReturn`. so in that case, if you have defined `mytable` as ListObject, then you only need the line `Set mytable = ShSReturn.ListObjects("Survey Return")`. Also, make sure `ShSReturn` is referenced properly to the right worksheet, because in your code looks like you have defined it as a Public Variable before.

Comment: I tried it and got another message that type mismatched. Thank you anyway for your quick replies.

Comment: @C.Edo - No. In order to start at row 7, you'd have to use a `For ... Next` loop. But you're using `For Each`. This means that `cell` will be set to each cell in the specified range, starting from the first cell *in that range*. The confusion is because you declared `cell` as a variant: then used it as an integer/long (setting it as 7), then effectively using it as a *Range* type in the loop. That overwrites the 7 value.

Comment: Are you sure `SurveyReturn` is a table? can you upload somewhere the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some confusion about the nature of your ListObject, as specified in your original code (see comments to the question). When you select a bunch of cells and go to Insert -> Table, then as well as the table object, Excel defines a **Range** with the name of that table: a named Range. This Range may be referenced directly in VBA as such:

```
Set mytable = Range("Table1")
```

Note that Range names may not contain spaces

On the assumption that you have a named Range, it might be something like this:

```
Sub LOf()
    Dim myrange As Long, lastrow As Long, finalrow As Long, resultrow As Long
    Dim mytable As Range
    lastrow = ShSReturn.Range("G" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    finalrow = ShSReturn.Range("C" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    resultrow = ShSReturn.Range("B" & ShSReturn.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set mytable = ActiveSheet.Range("SurveyReturn") ' It's best to specify which sheet your source data is on. Presumably "ShSReturn" is the CodeName of your results sheet

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 7 To mytable.Cells(mytable.Cells.Count).Row ' Start at Row 7, and finish at the row number of the last cell in that Range
        If mytable.Cells(x, **lastrow**).Value = "Ongoing" And mytable.Cells(x, **finalrow**).Value = "HP" Then
            mytable.Cells(x, **resultrow**).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(cell, 17).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            resultrow = resultrow + 1
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Note that the above code will not work in its present form. What I have done is an approximation of what I *think* you're looking for: however you're going to have to do a bit of work, because the code in your question has some fundamental issues. For example, in your code you have lines like this:

```
mytable.Cells(cell, resultrow).Copy
```

However addressed cells within Ranges are in the format Range.Cells(Row, **Column**) - where Row and Column are numbers. However in your code *resultrow* as defined at the top is a Row, not a Column. You need to work out what exactly you want to copy, in terms of which row/column and re-write your code accordingly.

If you want to provide clarity, I'll be happy to edit my answer to accommodate what you want.